# Error: Uncaught Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'function(){}'. Angular Universal in Prod

Tags: angular-universal

Receiving the following error when running angular universal in prod with spring:

```
 Uncaught Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'function(){}'.
    at e.resolve (main.a13a69d566149a0cec5b.js:1)
    at e.getNgModuleMetadata (main.a13a69d566149a0cec5b.js:1)
    at e._loadModules (main.a13a69d566149a0cec5b.js:1)
    at e._compileModuleAndComponents (main.a13a69d566149a0cec5b.js:1)
    at e.compileModuleAsync (main.a13a69d566149a0cec5b.js:1)
    at e.compileModuleAsync (main.a13a69d566149a0cec5b.js:1)
    at main.a13a69d566149a0cec5b.js:1
    at e.bootstrapModule (main.a13a69d566149a0cec5b.js:1)
    at Module.zUnb (main.a13a69d566149a0cec5b.js:1)
    at c (runtime.1261f568282a4018d1f8.js:1)
    at Object.0 (main.a13a69d566149a0cec5b.js:1)
    at c (runtime.1261f568282a4018d1f8.js:1)
    at t (runtime.1261f568282a4018d1f8.js:1)
    at Array.r [as push] (runtime.1261f568282a4018d1f8.js:1)
    at main.a13a69d566149a0cec5b.js:1
```

Have tried replacing dist/server with ../resources/templates/webapp